# from the button in form2 i want to add dynamic buttons in panel of form1. This code is not functioning

Tags: c#

[image]

the question is in the picture as well

I have done this but This code is not functioning

form1 (dashboard)

```
public partial class dashboard : Form
    {
        public static FlowLayoutPanel form1Panel;

        public dashboard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void dashboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form1Panel = flowLayoutPanel1;
        }
    }
```

in form 2

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Button btn = new Button
 {
       Text = TbAccName.Text,
       Width = 110,
       Height = 80                        
  };
  dashboard.form1Panel.Controls.Add(btn);
  dashboard obj = new dashboard();
  Hide();
  obj.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume we have two forms. `Form1` and `Form2`. In `Form1` we have `panel1`. We need to make this panel PUBLIC.

Try this code:

**Form1:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Panel form1Panel;

    ...

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form1Panel = panel1;
    }
}
```

And in `Form2` we can access to `form1Panel` like this:

**Form2:**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    ...

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button myButton = new Button { Text = TbAccName.Text, Width=110, Height=80 };
        Form1.form1Panel.Controls.Add(myButton);
    }
}
```

Hope that what you want.

Comment: i did the same and there is no error but the button is not added in the panel

Comment: @Neevan Did you dock your panel? Remember, the button created in the top-left of the panel.

Comment: i have used flowlayoutpanel so i don't think it is good to dock

Comment: @Neevan Ok. Please add your codes in your question.

Comment: @Neevan Button doesn't appear because you call `new dashboard()`. Why you do this? Form1 at the start must be shown and no need to call it again.

Comment: It works when i do not create new dashboard but i need to close the form2.
Thanks!